# Why are there no branches in Linux kernel source code?

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I am studying Linux kernel source code.
I went to the official github repository.

I see there is only a master branch.

I have read in some Git tutorials that it is not a good idea to work on the master branch.

I have read we must create a branch for each functionality.

So why does the kernel only have a master branch?

Comment: What you work on and what you decide to publish on GitHub are potentially two entirely different things.

Comment: `torvalds/linux` now has over 25k forks. As Git is a distributed system, we can consider all the forks and the main repo as a single repo. So at least it has 25k master branches. Though with the same name `master`, most of them are really different branches, not to mention that the forks usually have more than `master`.

Comment: Also it's fine to only work on the master branch: https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/

Comment: I have read somewhere that working on master branch is like login on system with root: Something to avoid

Comment: Ever heard "don't believe everything you read"?  That might be worth extra consideration in some fields.  I'd say anything that attracts teenage boys is likely extra susceptible to (at least attempted) bandwagonry..

Comment: While your question is off-topic on SO, I think it worth mentioning that your idea of how Linux is developed is very far removed from the reality ;-) Several key points: 1) most of the code gets into Linux via patch series sent to the dedicated mailing list; 2) each Linux subsystem has its own person, called "leutenant" which is responsible for reviewing those patches and integrating them into their own tree (Git repository); 3) Linus pulls changesets from the trees of his leutenants from time to time; 4) Dedicated mailing lists for particular subsystems do exist, too.

Comment: You may start [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/318699/) for instance. A very insightful post by Linus on how to handle transitions of KDE repos from Subversion to Git is given [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/246381/) — among other things, it discusses the paradigm of using multiple Git trees (repos). To recap the point I'm trying to get across is that a single centralized ("rendez-vouz") repo is only used for small Git projects; Git allows more interesting models of managing projects.

Comment: What you've found on Github is merely a so-called "mirror" of one particular Git repository hosting (some state of) Linux during its usual development lifecycle. As to project management, Github implements only a particular, and rather opinionated and limited, approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people said in the comments, it is not because there is only a master branch that there are no branches on local clones and other forks. The contributions don't necessarily pass via Github, and if you have a look at the commits log and crunch numbers, you will see that there are a lot of branch merges:

```
> git log --oneline --merges | egrep "Merge (branch|tag)" | wc -l
50914
```

On big public projects, it is probably a better idea to keep the main repository as mirror/reference and if you want to develop on in, you fork it. From here, you do what you want on it, create the branches you want, and when ready, push a contribution request via the project's favourite medium (PR, mail...). And when new changes are introduced in the project's `master`, the main repository is updated to get the change.